# FluentValidation - allow empty value for exact index in array

Tags: c#, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation to Validate my form.

I have a input field which is string[] up to 5 elements long and I need to Validate that Input to require **Elements[1][2][3]** values to be NotEmpty(), NotNull() and MinLength(2), MaxLength(250).

**Elements [4] and [5]** are supposed to allow Empty or require MinLength(2), MaxLength(25) and NotNull().

How do I do this? Because I'm not always sending 5 elements of that array, it could be in range 3-5 and I'm getting **IndexOutOfRangeException** with my current solution

I currently have that code

```
        When(x => x.Elements.Length <= 3, () =>
        {
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).NotEmpty().WithMessage(ValidationMessage.Required);
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).NotNull().WithMessage(ValidationMessage.Required);
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).MaximumLength(AppConstants.MaxChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MaxLength);
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).MinimumLength(AppConstants.MinChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MinLength);
        });
        When(x => x.Elements.Length > 3 && x.Elements.Length <= 5, () =>
        {
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).MaximumLength(AppConstants.MaxChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MaxLength);
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).MinimumLength(AppConstants.MinChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MinLength);
            RuleForEach(x => x.Elements).NotNull().WithMessage(ValidationMessage.Required);
            RuleFor(x => x.Elements[3]).MaximumLength(AppConstants.MaxChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MaxLength).When(el => el.Elements[3] != string.Empty);
            RuleFor(x => x.Elements[3]).MaximumLength(AppConstants.MinChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MinLength).When(el => el.Elements[3] != string.Empty);
            RuleFor(x => x.Elements[4]).MaximumLength(AppConstants.MaxChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MaxLength).When(el => el.Elements[4] != string.Empty);
            RuleFor(x => x.Elements[4]).MaximumLength(AppConstants.MinChars).WithMessage(ValidationMessage.MinLength).When(el => el.Elements[4] != string.Empty);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of array index starting from 0 confusion.

The condition you've set is

```
x.Elements.Length > 2 && x.Elements.Length <= 4
```

and trying to access

```
x.Elements[3]
x.Elements[4]
```

However,

- `x.Elements[3]` is **only** a valid index when `Elements.Length` >= 4
- `x.Elements[4]` is **only** a valid index when `Elements.Length` >= 5.

So your when condition should be changed to

```
x => x.Elements.Length >= 4 && x.Elements.Length <= 5
```

if you're explicitly checking for `Elements[3] && Elements[4]`